# Ideal way of creating a JFace dialog considering different screen resolutions and fonts

Tags: java, dialog, swt, jface

I have used grid layout in my dialog and I have several widgets wherein I'm not setting the height or width. But I'm setting the initial size of the dialog by overriding the `getInitialSize()` method.

```
@Override
protected Point getInitialSize()
{
    return new Point(400, 400); 
}
```

Will this cause the widgets inside the dialog to appear improperly (like partially hidden) ?

If yes , Would this issue be solved by using a `ScrolledComposite` inside the main composite? 
(so that even if the widgets are not proper, the scrolling would help viewing the complete widgets.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are worried that not all of your content will fit on the screen on all resolutions, here are a couple of things to consider:

1. Wrap your whole content in a `ScrolledComposite` (as you already mentioned).
2. Try splitting your content into several parts and either use a wizard type of GUI or tabs, depending on your requirements.
3. Try avoiding setting a fixed size for the window. Either let it compute its optimal size or at least set the size to a percentage of the screen.